# MYSQL DATE_FORMAT Function not working

Tags: mysql, date-format

I am currently working on a gig guide and would like to format the date as: Day - Month - Date

I'm using the following mysql query -

```
$query_getEvents = "SELECT gig_guide.date, gig_guide.artist, gig_guide.venue, 
gig_guide.tickets, DATE_FORMAT(gig_guide.date, '%M %e, %Y') 
FROM gig_guide ORDER BY gig_guide.date ASC";
```

Unfortunately the DATE_FORMAT is not formatting and keeps returning the standard 0000-00-00 format instead of the way I want it.

Any ideas what may have gone wrong with this code? Or could it be a direct problem with the database itself and the date structure.

Comment: using your code, it will return month day, year. However it is working fine with me. what version are you using?

Comment: Please show some sample data from your table and what datatype your column is.

Comment: I think you are supposed to put `''` like `DATE_FORMAT('gig_guide.date', '%M %e, %Y')` I don't know which language is this,may be php but I suspect this is the cause

Comment: @BhavikShah `'` is for text, the backticks are for column names.

Comment: is `gig_guide.date` string? if so, how was it formatted?

Answer (score 0):

If the month is not setted in gig_guide.date, the mysql can't make representation 00.month as a string.

Try it with some date which have month setted.